# Call PHP function with MySQLi and return TRUE OR FALSE

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I am migrating a PHP application from 5.5 to 7.
And mysql_query to mysqli_query

One of the function is used for authorisation of code blocks:
But it doesn't work with MySQLi_query. It worked OK with the mysql_query function. Anyone an idea how to fix this? TIA.

```
function IfMemberOfGroup($idgroup){    
$query = "SELECT user_id from member_of_group WHERE user_id = 
'".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND id_group IN (".$idgroup.")";     

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
return true;
}
                                  }
```

To use the function:

```
if ((IfMemberOfGroup("2"))===true){
//do something
}
```

Comment: $db is connection or database name ?
It should be mysqli_query($con, $query);

Comment: $db is connection string. Could also be $con.

Comment: Didn't get that, Since PHP function return once, then why you are returning in while loop?

Comment: Good point. How would you do it?

Comment: but $result will always (except errors) be object of mysqliResult, in loop, there is determined if some rows were returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if there is a record and then simply return the fact whether there is such a record in the `member_of_group` table or not

```
function IfMemberOfGroup($idgroup)
{    
  global $db;

  $query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from member_of_group 
    WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND id_group IN (".$idgroup."))";     

  $result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($db),E_USER_ERROR);
  $is_member = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];

  return (bool)$is_member;
}
```